# axios uses wrong URL when URL has dynamic params on ReactJS + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios

So I use axios to link my reactJS front-end with my rails API back-end.

here is my Router:

```
[...]
<Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true}/>
<Route path="/meals" component={MealsPage} exact={true}/>
<Route exact path="/user/:token"
                      render={routeProps => (
                        <MyAccountPage {...routeProps} currentUser={this.state} />
                      )}
              />
[...]
```

here is my function using axios:

```
getCurrentUser: jwt => {
    let config = {
      headers: {}
    }
    if (jwt) {
      config['headers']['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jwt
    }
    return axios.get('api/v1/users/current', config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if( error.response ){
            console.log(error: error.response.data);
        }
        return undefined
      })
  }
```

It works perfectly with the `/` and `/meals` routes. But when axios is called with `/user/:token` it tries to fetch data from `/user/api/v1/users/current` instead of `/api/v1/users/current`.

How can I change that so that it works for both dev and prod environment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the path in your `axios.get` request – because it doesn't start with a slash, it's taken as being relative to the current document path.

If your endpoint is at `/api/v1/users/current`, then that's the path you should specify in your request:

```
return axios.get('/api/v1/users/current', config)
  .then(...
```

Comment: you're right. Adding a "/" at the beginning of the path solved the problem. Thank you very much mate !